# XCode importing C++ project problems: "referenced from"

Tags: c++, xcode, import

I have some problems importing an existing C++ project into my XCode. I already resolved some issues on includes (the use of string.h from another library was a pain), and now I stumbled upon another problem.

When I build the project, I have 35 errors, all of the same origin.
For example:

`"_EVP_DigestInit_ex", referenced from:
      getParameterBdd(char*, char*, char*, char*, int)in main.o`

and

`"wxStringBase::InitWith(wchar_t const*, unsigned long, unsigned long)", referenced from:
            wxStringBase::wxStringBase(wchar_t const*)in main.o`

It just goes on and on like this, for almost every function I can find in my own code.
I must have forgotten something obvious, but I've found nothing on any forum that can help me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are linker errors; you can tell that from the fact that `.o` files are being processed. That means compilation must have succeeded to produce these.

Did you specify all the right libraries? By the looks of it, you need to link with at least OpenSSL (`-lssl -lcrypto -lz`) and wxWidgets.

Comment: I specified the needed libraries in the header search paths, but I didn't configure any linking, I guess there's my problem.

Comment: Any idea as to how I could link wxWidgets and the sqlite3 library? (added -lsqlite3 but that doesn't work...)

Comment: @glenn: I've no idea about wxWidgets, I never used that. In any case, for any library you installed yourself (rather than getting it with the OS), you'll have to point the linker to the directory containing it with `-L` (e.g., `-L/usr/local/lib`).